# Multiply-included header with guards

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, c11

Let's say I have a special header file which is designed to be included multiple times and generates different code depending on the value of some macro which must be defined before including it. For example, the following file `dumb.h`:

```
#define RETFUNC return_ ## VALUE
static inline int RETFUNC() {
  return VALUE;
}
```

You include it like:

```
#define VALUE 100
#include "dumb.h"
#define VALUE 200
#include "dumb.h"
```

and it generates two versions of the function like:

```
static inline return_100 {
  return 100;
}

static inline return_200 {
  return 200;
}
```

Great<sup>1</sup>.

How can I make a header guard for this type of file? Without guards, if two different consumers of the header file both requested the same `VALUE`, you'd get an error since two identical versions of the `return_*` function would be generated.

Now a normal header guard like:

```
#ifndef DUMB_H_
#define DUMB_H_
...
#endif // DUMB_H_
```

Isn't going to work since it would only effectively include the file once (the `#include` sequence above would generate the `_100` version of the function, but not the `_200` version).

In principle I would like to generate the *name* of a macro using token pasting, to check as the guard, like:

```
#ifndef DUMB_H_ ## VALUE
#define DUMB_H_ ## VALUE
...
```

But token pasting can't be used like that (outside of macro expansion).

Any there any other options to prevent this file from being included multiple times with the same `VALUE`, but to still allow the body to be effectively included once for each different `VALUE` requested?

---

<sup>1</sup> Not *great* in the sense that this is a good pattern or anything like that, but in it that it at least appears to work.

Comment: There's an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) here, I think.  Even assuming that the real functions are more complex than the ones shown here, why isn't the number an argument to a function?  How are you making the functions different?  Or do you need a function pointer that wraps a constant for use somewhere, and unlike C++ you can't make an object with storage that records the number and provides a function pointer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - yes, the real situation is more complex. This is an MCVE to illustrate the question. Evidently I'm not actually wanting to generate a function like `return_100`. `VALUE` is not necessarily a number, but may be something that cannot simply be passed be to a function (e.g., a type). The multiple-inclusion is pattern is occasionally useful so I'm interested in a specific solution to that problem, even if some other underlying problem admits a totally different solution. That is, I'm aware well of XY but here I'm interested mostly in this narrow question.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when the so called 'guarded header file' is included multiple times with the same VALUE. Compilation error? Even if you don't have a guard, if you define two functions with same name, it will throw a linking error.

Comment: @aneeshjose - no, in that case it should effectively be included just once for the given `VALUE`, as described at the end of the question. In the MCVE above it would generate exactly one `return_*` function for each distinct `VALUE` it was called with.

Comment: Ideally, your clarifying comments should be updates to the question.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - I further clarified the case of double-inclusion just now. Do you see anything else missing?

Comment: The first sentence should scream "no, bad design, don't do it!" to any experienced programmer. Is there a reason you can't use regular `#ifdef` compiler switches? Too easy and too readable?

Comment: @Lundin - can you elaborate on how that would work in answer? What do you mean by "compiler switches" - there are a lot of those...

Answer (score 0):

With the explanation in [comment 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47706465/macro-dependent-header-includes#comment82373378_47706465) and [comment 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47706465/macro-dependent-header-includes#comment82373400_47706465), I think the normal process is more like this.  I'm going to use a type as the argument, and generate a 'minimum' function for the different types:

#### `dumb.h`

```
#ifndef DUMB_H_INCLUDED
#define DUMB_H_INCLUDED

#define MIN_TYPE(x) \
    static inline x min_ ## x(x v1, x v2) { return (v1 < v2) ? v1 : v2; }

#endif /* DUMB_H_INCLUDED */
```

#### Consumer code

```
#include "dumb.h"
#include <inttypes.h>

MIN_TYPE(int)          // No semicolon; no empty declaration!
MIN_TYPE(double)
MIN_TYPE(uint64_t)

void write_minima(int i1, int i2, double d1, double d2, uint64_t u1, uint64_t u2)
{
    printf("Minima: (%d, %g, %" PRIu64 ")\n",
           min_int(i1, i2), min_double(d1, d2), min_uint64_t(u1, u2));
}
```

This does not stop you from trying to instantiate the same function twice in a single TU (translation unit), but the compiler will object if you do that.  And frankly, letting the compiler do the complaining is simpler than trying to make the C preprocessor spot that you've screwed up and rectify your mistake.

If the C code will be generated by another program, then you need to ensure that the code generator keeps a track of what it has requested and ensure that it doesn't double generate the code.

Comment: That's fine (and so is the solution in the OP) if the `dumb.h` is just used by one `.c` file directly. The problem though is that some particular `MIN_TYPE(int)` might be used all over the place by header files. It isn't possible to solve the "double inclusion" problem in that case, without an unreasonable about of coordination between the headers, and even then it will break when you include two headers that both wanted `MIN_TYPE`.

Comment: I postulated that the functions are `static inline`.  That means that _if_ they are called, then they are local to the file, and hopefully the functions actually won't even exist (they will have been inlined).  There's an element of "that's a cheat", but in some contexts it will work.  There's no way the C compiler can spot that you create the same external function name in different TUs; it only works on one TU at a time until it links them together, and then the linker will complain.  If you have a set of functions that are too big to inline and must be instantiated, _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ If you have a set of functions that are too big to inline and must be instantiated, then the header should be used to declare them.  Repeated declarations are not a problem.  And you have one or more  implementation files that define the functions that are actually needed, using some mechanism related to what I've shown (except the definitions are not `static inline`). As I said in the main answer, it feels like you're trying to use the preprocessor to head off a problem that is actually a programmer error that should be diagnosed by the compiler and fixed by the programmer.

Comment: I think you misunderstood (or I did). I'm not talking about the problem of repeatedly declaring the same `static inline` function in different TUs (that is common and guaranteed to work fine). I'm saying you will end up redeclaring the same function in the _same_ TU. You address it in your question: _This does not stop you from trying to instantiate the same function twice in a single TU._ - with the implication you can simply "not do that". The problem is that two independent header files that both want to use the same `MIN_TYPE(int)` will need a `MIN_TYPE(int)` line to declare the function.

Comment: ... but as soon as those two header files (which have done nothing wrong) are both included by one `.c` file (which is also doing nothing wrong) you'll have two `min_int` declarations in the same TU, and this won't compile. I don't see how you can resolve that in general. So I really see the problem as analagous to standard header includes: as many headers can include `<stdlib.h>` without any issue since you only get one declaration (and definition for things declared inline in the header, which isn't going to be much) per TU.

Comment: OK; I see where you're driving now.  Traditional C shuns the idea of functions defined (as opposed to declared) in headers.  This sort of … well, I'm going to call it a mess but that might be unduly pejorative; this sort of mess is avoided entirely if you only declare functions in headers.  At this point, I would need to be convinced that the independent headers that are capable of defining the same functions are a good idea.  However, I can see that once you start down the route of embedding function definitions in headers, you could start running into the problem you outline.

Comment: You are right though that if the functions were _defined_ out of line (not in the header), then the problem would be solved since repeated _declarations_ are OK - but that then you have to organize somehow to include all the needed definitions to be included in the final executable. In my case I'm looking for a "header only" solution, i.e., the equivalent of a bunch of `static inline` functions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160756/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-beeonrope).